# Tags vs functions in twig extensions

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently writing some extensions in twig, but I am having trouble deciding why a certain extension should be implemented as a tag or a function.

Twig's [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#) lists the following 2 constructs and what they do:

- `{{ }}`: used to print the result of an expression evaluation;
- `{% %}`: used to execute statements.

I am planning to implement something similiar to symfony2's [embedded controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers).

Why is it that the feature is implemented as:

```
{% render "AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:fancy" with { 'name': name, 'color': 'green' } %}
```

Since the embedded controllers function should return a fully rendered template for the requested controller, wouldn't a function be more appropriate?

```
render("AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:fancy", { 'name': name, 'color': 'green' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was intereseted in the same question. It's up to you to decide.

If you use `{{ }}` you will be able to apply filters to the output: `{{ render()|upper }}`. If you use `{% %}` the output of your extension won't be "sanitized" (but you can always use `{{ }}`  with `array('is_safe' => array('all')`).

`render` is an important construction. It's not just a function like `{{ path() }}` that you can call in an expression: `{{ host ~ path() }}`.